# Differential Equation- Need help (Analytical)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need help in solving the differential equation below. It would be nice if someone can help me out or guide how can I proceed.  I have looked into many references, but I could not find something similar to the problem I have. 
$$ \ddddot{x} + \frac{w_1}{w_2}\ddot{x}+\frac{1}{w_2}\lambda(t) =0 $$

where, $$ \lambda(t)= -c_1\cdot t + c_2 $$ and $$w_1, w_2, c_1, c_2\text{ are constants.}$$

Thanks in advance. 
PS- I need to solve this analytically

Comment: Look for "Linear Nonhomogeneous Systems"

Comment: Thank you, I checked. Not very successful yet.

Comment: To obtain a particular solution, it is very important if you can tell $w_1,w_2>0$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just slammed that into Mathematica and got
$$
x(t)\to \frac{t^2 (c_1 t-3 c_2)-6 \text{w2}
    \left(C_1 \cos \left(\frac{t \sqrt{\text{w1}}}{\sqrt{\text{w2}}}\right)+C_2
    \sin \left(\frac{t \sqrt{\text{w1}}}{\sqrt{\text{w2}}}\right)\right)}{6
    \text{w1}}+C_4 t+C_3
$$
where the captial $C_i$ are MMA's constants and the lowercase are your ones. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello,  Yes indeed with Dsolve we can get this. I wanted to understand the procedure actually.

Comment: @PrateekTiwari Based on the solution, perhaps you could look at it as a second order equation in terms of $\ddot{x}$, to get  $$ \ddot{y} + \frac{w_1}{w_2}y+\frac{1}{w_2}\lambda(t) =0 $$ this is likely where the double integration constant $C_3 + C_4 t$ comes from.

Comment: Yeah. I will try. Thank you for your response